# How to transfer unicode string from c# to c/c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I call a C/C++ DLL function from C# and have a problem when the function has a `wchar_t* parameter`.
I modified the parameter from `wchar_t*` to `char*`, then everything is ok.
Why? how to make it work well with `wchar_t*`?

Here is my code:

C#

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string fileName, IntPtr hFile, uint loadFlag);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr lib, string funcName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr lib);

delegate void DllTestFunc(string str, byte[] data, int length);

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var dllInstance = LoadLibraryEx(@"D:\Development\NativeDll\x64\Debug\NativeDll.dll", IntPtr.Zero, 0x0008);
    var ptr = GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "DllTestFunc");
    var func = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<DllTestFunc>(ptr);
    var inputStr = @"E:\test.dat";
    var data = new byte[100];
    data[0] = 0x55;
    func(inputStr, data, 2020);
    FreeLibrary(dllInstance);
}
```

C/C++ Code:

```
void __stdcall DllTestFunc(wchar_t* str1, unsigned char* data, const int length)

{

    cout << str1 << endl;

    cout << int(data[0]) << endl;

    cout << length << endl;**strong text**

}
```

Because I need to use the `wchar_t*`, how to resolve it?

Comment: use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)` attribute

Comment: Is it necessary to load the library at run-time (using `LoadLibrary`) or can you import the method directly via `[DllImport("...NativeDll.dll")]`?

Comment: You can make life a lot easier by using `DllImport`. If you need that `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` flag for `LoadLibraryEx`, then simply call `LoadLibraryEx` before you call any `DllImport` functions.

Comment: using marshal as is the best answer. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to tell the marshaller how to transfer the `str` argument of your delegate:

```
delegate void DllTestFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str, byte[] data, int length);
```